# getting error in Case statement SQL getting NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Iam using SQL to get query in report builder, i have put case statement in sql query but i am getting NULL in month col

```
    select * into #temp from
(select count(*) [Total Clients], li.title,
 SUBSTRING(li.title,CHARINDEX('_',li.title,CHARINDEX('_',li.title)+1)+1,2) as 'month1',
 CASE WHEN 'month1' = '01' THEN 'Jan'
            WHEN 'month1' = '02' THEN 'Feb'
            WHEN 'month1' = '03' THEN 'Mar'
            WHEN 'month1' = '04' THEN 'Apr'
            WHEN 'month1' = '05' THEN 'May'
            WHEN 'month1' = '06' THEN 'June'
            WHEN 'month1' = '07' THEN 'Jul'
            WHEN 'month1' = '08' THEN 'Aug'
            WHEN 'month1' = '09' THEN 'Sep'
            WHEN 'month1' = '10' THEN 'Oct'
            WHEN 'month1' = '11' THEN 'Nov'
            WHEN 'month1' = '12' THEN 'Dec'
            END As [Month],
li.CI_UniqueID,coll.name,coll.CollectionID,
SUM (CASE WHEN ucs.status=3 or ucs.status=1  then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'Installed / Not Applicable',
sum( case When ucs.status=2 Then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'Required',
sum( case When ucs.status=0 Then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'Unknown',
round((CAST(SUM (CASE WHEN ucs.status=3 or ucs.status=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as float)/count(*) )*100,2) as 'Compliant%',
    round((CAST(count(case when ucs.status not in('3','1') THEN '*' end) as float)/count(*))*100,2) as 'NotCompliant%'
    From v_Update_ComplianceStatusAll UCS
inner join v_r_system sys on ucs.resourceid=sys.resourceid
inner join v_FullCollectionMembership fcm on ucs.resourceid=fcm.resourceid
inner join v_collection coll on coll.collectionid=fcm.collectionid
inner join v_AuthListInfo LI on ucs.ci_id=li.ci_id
where coll.CollectionID like '%SMS00001%' and
--title like '%SUG%' 
 Title like '%P1%' and
Title like '%SUG_' + '' + CAST(year(getdate()) as varchar) +  '' + '%'
--or Title like '%SUG_' + '' + CAST(year(getdate())-1 as varchar) +  '' + '%'
group by li.title,li.CI_UniqueID,coll.name,coll.CollectionID) as e
```

this is query output iam getting is NULL value in month col

please find picture

[image]

can you please help why iam getting NULL in month COL

Comment: You are comparing literals and 'month1' = '02' will never be true.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this,

```
select count(*) [Total Clients], li.title,
 SUBSTRING(li.title,CHARINDEX('_',li.title,CHARINDEX('_',li.title)+1)+1,2) as 'month1',
 CASE SUBSTRING(li.title,CHARINDEX('_',li.title,CHARINDEX('_',li.title)+1)+1,2) 
            WHEN '01' THEN 'Jan'
            WHEN '02' THEN 'Feb'
            WHEN '03' THEN 'Mar'
            WHEN '04' THEN 'Apr'
            WHEN '05' THEN 'May'
            WHEN '06' THEN 'June'
            WHEN '07' THEN 'Jul'
            WHEN '08' THEN 'Aug'
            WHEN '09' THEN 'Sep'
            WHEN '10' THEN 'Oct'
            WHEN '11' THEN 'Nov'
            WHEN '12' THEN 'Dec'
            END As [Month],
li.CI_UniqueID,coll.name,coll.CollectionID ....
```

Or handle it in an outer query

Answer (score 0):

Your case `expression` would be something

```
(case (SUBSTRING(li.title,CHARINDEX('_',li.title,CHARINDEX('_',li.title)+1)+1,2))
    when '01' then 'Jan'
    ... 
 end)
```

You are using alise as column name

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `CASE` statement with this:

```
 case when SUBSTRING(li.title,CHARINDEX('_',li.title,CHARINDEX('_',li.title)+1)+1,2) between '01' and '12' 
      then convert( char(3),cast( '2018/'+ SUBSTRING(li.title,CHARINDEX('_',li.title,CHARINDEX('_',li.title)+1)+1,2) +'/01' as datetime),0)  
 end as [MONTH],
```